# ACF - Eliminate unnecessary data and print

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, regex

In ACF, the_field('battery'); outputs as follows :

```
Battery : Sony Rechargeable Ni-MH 2200 mAh battery
```

or

```
Battery : Energizer AA Rechargeable Batteries 2300 mAh NiMH
```

How can i achieve this (showing only mAh details) :

```
Battery : 2200 mAh
```

or

```
Battery : 2300 mAh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a regex, in this case, to extract the needed value from a string:

```php
$string = 'Energizer AA Rechargeable Batteries 2300 mAh NiMH';

preg_match('/([0-9]+\s*mah)/i', $string, $capacity );
    
if ( isset( $capacity[0] ) ) {
    printf('Battery: %s', $capacity[0] );
}
```

This regex `/([0-9]+\s*mah)/i` will look for any numbers followed by case insensitive `mah` combination.

You can test this regex online here https://regex101.com/r/KDdHbp/1/

Also, here is documentation on `preg_match` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php